# Fantasy TV Show from the 80s i saw on Public Television when a kid

Tags: story-identification, magic, merlin

I really vaguely remember this television program with this actor that had striking blue eyes kinda looked like Ramsey Snow from game of thrones.  The show was about a boy whom was sent back in time to the time of Merlin? or perhaps the middle ages and was becoming a wizard and learning to use his magic ability.  There may have been some sort of magical items involved and time travel for sure.  but what was most striking was this kids or teens blue eyes.  I beleieve it was on public television for a while in the 80s.  the Actor wasnt really a kid but maybe in his teens. I just want to know who this guy was and what show I was watching because i keep remembering small snippets of it now and then.  Like him disappearing or appearing in a forest near some river.  Just really vague things.

Comment: What country was this?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't quite match your description, but the "blue eyes" reference makes me think of Jon-Erik Hexum from [Voyagers!](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083500/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

Factors that match to some degree:

- Aired in the early 1980's
- Plot centered on time travel
- One of the two leads was a younger man with blue eyes, other was a younger boy
- Used a device to travel in time

[image]

Comment: The main character was trained, etc. to be a time traveler, looking for cases where time had gone awry and had to put it back on track.  He had ... slacked ... during his training and didn't remember much about history.  The kid had actually paid attention in history classes, so he was able to figure out what went wrong, what needed to be done, etc.  You are correct about the main actor.  Meeno Peluce was the kid.